# How can I set vue-i18n messages through a plugin injected function in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I'm using `vue-i18n` and trying to set my messages using an injected function but I'm having an issue understanding why my messages are set in the server but when it's hydrated in the client the messages are empty. As you can see I set the translations in the asyncData method by using a method I `inject`. I can see the json in the server but once the client is hydrated they become an empty object again.. Am I wrong calling it in the asyncData method? I'm trying to move away from using store/vuex.

```js
// pages/index.vue

// here's my code for my page
asyncData({ $setTranslations }) {
  const data = fetch('/data') // fetch data from api
  $setTranslations(data.language)
}
```

```js
// /plugins/translate.js
 
// my translate plugin
export default(context, inject) {
  inject('setTranslations', async (locale) => {
    await setMsgsForLocale(locale)
  })
  // init i18n
  app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en', // default will change when data is retrieved
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {
      en: {},
      es: {},
    },
  })

async function setMsgsForLocale(language = 'en') {
  // fetch json 
  fetch(`/translations/${language}.json`)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then((messages) => {
    app.i18n.locale = language
    // set messages here
    app.i18n.setLocalMessage(language, messages)
    return messages
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I ended up returning the json fetched from the server and set them as a property of my page then I merge the messages

`asyncData() {
    const translations = $setTranslations(data.language)
    return { translations }
  },
  data: () => ({ translations: { } }),
  created() {
    this.$i18n.mergeLocaleMessage(this.$i18n.locale, this.translations)
  }`

looks wack but it works